# Why is the residual image still displayed on the screen after closing TMediaPlayer

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I have two screens, one of which displays the software interface on screen A, and the other screen B displays video and image information.

Now, I need to display a video on screen B. After the video is played, I need to display a `TPNGImage`. The problem is that, there is a problem displaying `TPNGImage` after the video is played, and the screen is still showing the last frame of the video. The `ReDrowMyself()` function is called using a timer, the image is a PNG image, 2160 * 3840.

```cpp
void CSensory_Test::play_stop()
{
    Form_Main->pForm_pg->Image_qmian->Visible = true;
    Form_Main->pForm_pg->MediaPlayer1->Close();
}

void CSensory_Test::ReDrowMyself()
{
    //
    if(Form_Main->pForm_pg == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    if(Form_Main->pForm_pg->Image_qmian->Visible)
    {
       try
       {
           Form_Main->pForm_pg->MediaPlayer1->Close();
       }
       catch(...)
       {

       }
    }
    
    TRect myrect(0,0,g_qm_width,g_qm_height);
    Form_Main->pForm_pg->Image_qmian->Canvas->StretchDraw(myrect,gqmGraphic);
}
```

I look forward to immediately displaying the images I need after closing `TMediaPlayer` playback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnNotify` event to trigger the display of the image.

To trigger the `OnNotify` event at the end of the video, you must set (Delphi syntax) `Mediaplayer.Notify := True` just before you call `MediaPlayer.Play`.

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> OnNotify occurs upon the completion of a media control method (Back, Close, Eject, Next, Open, Pause, PauseOnly, Play, Previous, Resume, Rewind, StartRecording, Step, or Stop) **when the Notify property is set to true before the call to the media control method**. After an OnNotify event, the Notify property must be reset to true for the next OnNotify event to occur.

To clear the last picture call
`MediaPlayer1.Close;`